# Gibbs sampling for correlated random variables

Tags: correlation, references, gibbs

## Short summary

Suppose two latent variables of a hierarchical model are correlated. Let $1-\epsilon$ be the degree of correlation. As $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ the variables become perfectly correlated and Gibbs sampling appears to only be possible if the two variables are considered as one variable (i.e. using block-Gibbs). Is this indeed the case or am I lacking understanding?

Edit: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_sampling#Failure_modes) discusses this problem in their section on "Failure modes". However, there is no reference or resolution to the problem.

## Complete question with example

Consider a population whose members have two binary attributes: age $X$ and health $Y$. We encode the variables as 
$$X=\begin{cases}0&\text{if young}\\1&\text{if old}\end{cases}$$ 
and $$Y=\begin{cases}0&\text{if healthy}\\1&\text{if sick}\end{cases}.$$
Let the joint probability distribution be given by
$$
P\left(X=x\cap Y=y\right)\equiv p_{xy}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{array}{cc}1-\epsilon&\epsilon\\\epsilon&1-\epsilon\end{array}\right)
$$
such that $\sum_{xy}p_{xy}=1$. Let us expand the probability distribution such that
$$
P\left(X=x\cap Y=y\right) = P\left(Y=y|X=x\right)P\left(X=x\right),
$$
where
$$
\begin{align}
P\left(X=x\right)\equiv p_x &=\sum_y p_{xy}=\frac{1}{2}\quad\forall x\\
P\left(Y=y|X=x\right)\equiv p_{y|x}&=\frac{p_{xy}}{p_x}=\begin{cases}1-\epsilon&\text{if }x=y\\\epsilon&\text{if }x\neq y\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

Suppose we make a noisy observation of the state of health an individual $\hat{Y}$ with error rate $\delta$ such that $P\left(\hat{y}=y|Y=y\right)=1-\delta$. We construct a hierarchical model as shown in the figure below. [image]

To use a Gibbs sampler, we construct the conditional distributions (assuming a flat prior on $X$) $$
P\left(X=x|Y=y\right)=\begin{cases}1-\epsilon&\text{if }x=y\\\epsilon&\text{if }x\neq y\end{cases}$$
$$
P\left(Y=y|X=x\cap\hat{Y}=\hat{y}\right)\propto\begin{cases}1-\epsilon&\text{if }y=x\\\epsilon&\text{if }y\neq x\end{cases}\times\begin{cases}1-\delta&\text{if }y=\hat{y}\\\delta&\text{if }y\neq \hat{y}\end{cases}.
$$

However, in the limit $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ knowledge of $x$ gives us full knowledge of $y$ and Gibbs sampling is no longer possible because the sampler gets stuck: If $X=0$, then $P\left(Y=y|X=0\cap\hat{Y}=\hat{y}\right)=\delta_{y0}\quad\forall\hat{y}$ and vice versa. What is the best way to deal with this situation?

Comment: Do you not like the idea of blocking from a theoretical or practical point of view?

Comment: Happy with blocking but a reference explaining the theoretical foundations of blocking in the context of perfectly correlated variables would be nice.